# How to write a Dockerfile for deploying Sinatra app to Heroku

Tags: ruby, docker, heroku, dockerfile, sinatra

I'm starting a personal project to learn more about Ruby and Sinatra. My personal project is to build a simple web server with Ruby without Rails that responds with your current IP + current time (in HTML) . Then I want to write a dockerfile for the service and deploy it on Heroku.

But problems always arise when the docker image has been deployed on Heroku. I think it's because When deploying a container app on Heroku, they require that Dockerfiles are configured to intake the randomly assigned port on a dyno - exposed as the $PORT environmental variable. Even though Docker allows for the usage of EXPOSE to specify which port for an image to use, Heroku ignores those commands and goes by the port assigned to a dyno.

So How do I exactly write the dockerfile, config.ru, gemfile and ruby file for this task? Any help would be appreciated!

dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:3.0.1

WORKDIR /Desktop
COPY . /Desktop
RUN bundle install

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rackup"]
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
gem 'puma'
gem 'reel'
gem 'http'
gem 'webrick'
```

Config.ru:

```
require './test'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Test.rb (main ruby file):

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'socket'

#find final_ip
addr_infos = Socket.ip_address_list
final_ip = ''
addr_infos.each do |addr_info|
    final_ip = final_ip + ' ' + addr_info.ip_address
end

#find current time
cur_time = Time.now.ctime

#set port
set :port, ENV["PORT"] || 3000

#print to html
get '/' do
    '<h2> Current Time: </h2> <br>' + cur_time + '<br><br>' + '<h2> Current IP Address: </h2> <br>'+final_ip
end
```